# CMakeLists.txt - run process, then execute command

Tags: cmake

I have the following `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0.0)
project(FlaAlgoTests)
...

include_directories("../lib")
...

add_executable(
        flamenco_algorithms_anomaly_stiction_tests
        ...
)
```

The `flamenco_algorithms_anomaly_stiction_tests` executable generates a `.xml` file when it is complete.

I would like to run a process (I guess using `ADD_CUSTOM_COMMAND`?) after this executable is run, which converts that xml file to an html file.

How can I do this?

Comment: You want to run this process - a) with cmake configuration? b) along the compilation of your project? c) after compilation of your project? d) as cmake unit test (add_test())? This really looks like a test, maybe you should just `add_test()` it.

Comment: add_test() does not run the command line tool which generates the html report.

Comment: What html report? You only mentioned xml file. I think it rules out point d). What about point a) `execute_process()`? and point  b) `add_custom_command(POST_BUILD/PRE_BUILD`? and point  c) `add_custom_target + add_custom_command` ?

Comment: I've just answered question which had really similar requirements - custom target which uses executable build within project to process some files:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/56394554/5945883

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is yes; you can use `ADD_CUSTOM_COMMAND` to first execute your built executable (`flamenco_stiction_tests.exe`), and second to run the additional process (`my_additional_process.exe`). Try something like this:

```
add_custom_command(TARGET flamenco_algorithms_anomaly_stiction_tests POST_BUILD
    COMMAND flamenco_stiction_tests.exe 
    COMMAND my_additional_process.exe my_generated_file.xml
    WORKING_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/Debug
    COMMENT "Running built executable and additional process..."
)
```

Per the CMake [documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_custom_command.html), these will be executed in order. You may also configure a script to run after the executable is built instead, using a combination of `configure_file()` and `add_custom_command`. Guaranteeing your generated file is available for the second process may be easier and safer that way.

Comment: This will run the command after every single build, which is *not* what I want to do.

What I want to do, as described, is have some kind of target which, when I launch the target, builds the `flamenco_algorithms_anomaly_stiction_tests` if necessary, *always* runs it (generating the xml file), and then runs a command-line tool on that.

Comment: @Daniel Paczuski Bak You didn't specify that constraint in your question. If that is the case, you probably want `add_custom_target()` instead, along with `add_dependencies()` to make your custom target build `flamenco_algorithms_anomaly_stiction_tests` if necessary.